# Find longest increasing sequence in groups of consecutive dates using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mariadb, sequence

Using MARIA-DB 10.6

I have a table `user` containing columns `dates` and `solved` for each row. Dates will always be unique (only 1 row of any date, if present). The solved count can be same, or higher, as the dates roll by.

Here's an example table `user`:

| date | solved |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-11-26 | 2 |
| 2010-11-27 | 4 |
| 2010-11-28 | 6 |
| 2010-11-29 | 10 |
| 2010-12-05 | 11 |
| 2010-12-06 | 11 |
| 2010-12-07 | 11 |
| 2010-12-08 | 12 |
| 2010-12-09 | 12 |
| 2010-12-10 | 12 |

What I need to find from this is: **the longest sequence of consecutive dates, where the solved count is increasing.**

Now the way I approached it is that there's 2 parts to this. First part is finding the groups of consecutive days. Following [this article](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-series-of-events-in-sql/), I have achieved that with this query:

```
WITH consecutiveDateGroups AS (
  SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS rowNum,
   DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL (-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date)) DAY) AS consecutiveDateGroup,
   date,
   solved
  FROM user
)

SELECT *
FROM consecutiveDateGroups
ORDER BY rowNum
```

In my case, we have 3 groups of consecutive dates:

[group 1] -> 2010-11-26 to 2010-11-29 (4 days)

[group 2] -> 2010-12-05 to 2010-12-10 (6 days)

I can group by the number of consecutive days in each group with this query:

```
WITH 
            
consecutiveDateGroups AS (
  SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS rowNum,
   DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL (-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date)) DAY) AS consecutiveDateGroup,
   date
  FROM user
)
            
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS consecutiveDates,
  MIN(date) AS minDate,
  MAX(date) AS maxDate
FROM consecutiveDateGroups
GROUP BY consecutiveDateGroup
```

The result I have so far is:

| consecutiveDates | minDate | maxDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2010-11-26 | 2010-11-29 |
| 6 | 2010-12-05 | 2010-12-10 |

I am all good so far. But after this is where things get muddy for me, and I am stuck. **How do I return the number of increasing solved columns for each consecutive date group?**

For example, in this case:

[group 1] has an increasing sequence of 4 [2,4,6,10]

[group 2] has an increasing sequence of 2 [11,12]

**So the result I want is:**

| consecutiveDates | minDate | maxDate | increasingSolvedSequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2010-11-26 | 2010-11-29 | 4 |
| 6 | 2010-12-05 | 2010-12-10 | 2 |

Any help would be appreciated!

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=c80ffb091bb272b0c3b2ae8abbbbbaf1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
set @cn = 1;
WITH consecutiveDateGroups AS 
(
  SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS rowNum,
   DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL (-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date)) DAY) AS consecutiveDateGroup,
   date,
   solved
  FROM user
)
, 
cte AS
(
 SELECT *,
 COALESCE(LEAD(solved) OVER (PARTITION BY consecutiveDateGroup ORDER BY date), solved) AS LD
 FROM consecutiveDateGroups
 ORDER BY rowNum
),
cte2 as 
(
 SELECT *,
 CASE WHEN solved <> ld THEN @cn:=@cn+1 ELSE @cn:=1 END AS ch
 FROM cte
)
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS consecutiveDates,
  MIN(date) AS minDate,
  MAX(date) AS maxDate,
  MAX(ch) AS increasingSolvedSequence  
FROM cte2
GROUP BY consecutiveDateGroup
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=4f7bcc6e06a133ed9ea58016c16fb35e).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, the DISTINCT(solved) will not cover cases where date groups have many distinct solved counts, but they are not necessarily increasing. Like in this case:

[2,4,6,10] -> longest inc. seq is 4 here vs [11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16] longest inc. seq is 2 here.

Fiddle to show this:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=fac1657c9b7719f42f624217a2e49255

Comment: Can you explain more about what is the longest increasing sequence, I thought that it's the distinct values of the solved.

Comment: An increasing sequence is a series of numbers where each one is higher than the previous one. Like [1,2,3,4] is an increasing series of numbers because 2>1, 3>2, 4>3. However, [1,2,2,3] is not a true increasing sequence because of the 2,2 in the middle. 2 is not greater than 2, so that repeated 2 in the middle ruins the sequence. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The answer has been updated, kindly, check it and let me know if it's OK.

Comment: Thank you very much Ahmed! This works perfectly. You have helped me get unstuck after many days of struggling. Seriously, thank you!!!!!!!!!